Is javascript syntax highlighting working?
From here, it seems that syntax highlighting should work.
However, it doesn't seem to work for the javascript question I asked earlier, and some others - e.g:
Bitcore-p2p: Peer.connect does not work
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/76394/34190
Invalid checksum when generating BIP-39 Mnemonic
But it does work for other questions:
How to build a transaction using bitcoinjs-lib
Could it be something to do with my setup? Or is this a problem?

Syntax highlighting is only active when the code block is marked with the specific language. To that end, enclose your code block in three backticks followed by the language and three closing backticks:
```js
let variable = value
let something = new Class(variable)
```


Thanks, just saw your edit and realised - right there in the help section too!

It's automatic on stackoverflow, that's what threw me.
